# How to capture/console the value of checked/uncheked checkbox into an array of object in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some checkboxes with parent-child structure whose values are coming from loop.Here when I click submit button I need to capture the selected/unselected value into below format(mentioned as commented output). When I click submit for preselected value is working fine, but if I remove checked from html(unselected on page load) and click submit that time it shows empty array.As per my requirement in project sometimes all checkboxes will be preselected,some times few selected/few unselected and some times all will be unselected based on condition and I need to capture selected/unselected value(same as output) on submit. Here is the code below
Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar5apb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
 Checkbox - 
    <div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
      <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{item.name}}</li>
        <li class="childData">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input checked type="checkbox" (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]" ></span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


      </ul>


      <div><button type="submit" (click)="getit()">submit</button></div>
    </div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  nestedjson: any;
  message = "";
  test: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nestedjson = [
      { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
      { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
      { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
    ];

   this.nestedjson.forEach(
      v => (v.checked = Array(v.value.length).fill(true))
    );
  }
  getit() {
    var duplicatePushArray = [];

    this.nestedjson.forEach(item => {
      let checked = [];
      item.checked.forEach((isCkecked, i) => {
        if (isCkecked) {
          checked.push(item.value[i]);
        }
      });
      if (checked.length > 0) {
        duplicatePushArray.push({
          name: item.name,
          value: checked
        });
      }
    });
    console.log("Final Array: ", duplicatePushArray);
  /*  output: [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]*/
  }
}
```

Comment: look into angular reactive forms and `FormArray`: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: With reactive form it will be difficult i think to capture in that format,Can you please help me on it

Comment: if you want the final value to be `[{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]` how do you know which checkboxes are checked and which not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.checked[i]" (change)="item.checked[i] = $event.target.checked">
```

or try template forms

```
<input type="checkbox" [name]="'checked_' + i" [(ngModel)]="item.checked[i]">
```

Make sure to import the forms module

Here is a reduce function that starts with an empty array, filters the values based on the checked array and the pushes a new object into the results if there are any checked ones with the checked results.

```
getit() {
  var duplicatePushArray = this.nestedjson.reduce((results, item) => {
    const checked = item.value.filter((value, index) => item.checked[index]);
    if (checked.length) {
      results.push({ name: item.name, value: checked });
    }
    return results;
  }, []);
  console.log("Final Array: ", duplicatePushArray);
}
```

Here is an update to your StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aasetj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That is fine but how to capture in this format  [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}] ,Can  you please create a demo

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise your solution was working for the checkboxes and you were looking to get the results, I updated the answer with a mod to your StackBlitz.

Comment: For preselected it is working fine,you can test the output in console on my demo.Now remove 'checked' from html and select manually and click submit, in this case expected output is not coming properly as per selection. I need to get the proper output in both the cases.

Comment: [checked]="item.checked[i]"

Comment: Again Suppose my first checkbox is preselected and others are not selected and click submit,that time also should get proper output

Comment: Still output is not coming properly as per selection if I remove checked from html and manually select and click submit. If you check the output in console in my given demo you can understand https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar5apb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: you remove the checked from your html, and then refresh your page,now you will get all checkbox are unselected. Then select child1 of parent1 and child2 of parent2 the output should come   [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]}]